# Removing animation from Angular Material Tooltip (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, tooltip, css-animations, angular-material2

I am using Angular 4 and have implemented the Angular Material tooltip within my app as shown below (it all is working fine)

However once I hover over the tooltip #nav div the tooltip animates and I cannot see any property in the official docs to disable this - what is the best way to disable this animation just for this element

https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api

```
<div id="nav" matTooltip="Filter" 
     matTooltipShowDelay="1000" 
     matTooltipPosition="above">
```

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: I don't believe I got around it and just kept with the animation in the end

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and I believe that currently the answer is: we can't do it. I mean we could, but we would need to fork material, or create a pull request and wait for acceptance.

Tooltip code can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/tooltip/tooltip.ts), it imports [file called tooltip-animations](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/tooltip/tooltip-animations.ts). As we can see, the tooltip is animated by javascript, so we can't easily overwrite it with css. Some extracts from the code:

```
show(delay: number): void {
// Cancel the delayed hide if it is scheduled
if (this._hideTimeoutId) {
  clearTimeout(this._hideTimeoutId);
  this._hideTimeoutId = null;
}

// Body interactions should cancel the tooltip if there is a delay in showing.
this._closeOnInteraction = true;
this._showTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
  this._visibility = 'visible';
  this._showTimeoutId = null;

  // Mark for check so if any parent component has set the
  // ChangeDetectionStrategy to OnPush it will be checked anyways
  this._markForCheck();
}, delay);
```

It shows how the "delay" parameter that we can pass to tolltip from our apps is just a parameter passed to timeout function before changing properties of tooltip.

```
 tooltipState: trigger('state', [
state('initial, void, hidden', style({opacity: 0, transform: 'scale(0)'})),
state('visible', style({transform: 'scale(1)'})),
transition('* => visible', animate('200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1)', keyframes([
  style({opacity: 0, transform: 'scale(0)', offset: 0}),
  style({opacity: 0.5, transform: 'scale(0.99)', offset: 0.5}),
  style({opacity: 1, transform: 'scale(1)', offset: 1})
]))),
transition('* => hidden', animate('100ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1)', style({opacity: 0}))),])
```

It shows how visibility change will be animated by angular animations framework and will last 100-200ms.

I can't see any way to modify this behaviour from an app that uses mat-tooltip.